# Nginx Rewrite rule depending on subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to serve 2 different versions of a file for a given URL, depending on the site subdomain.

Here's what i'm trying now:

```
location /robots.txt {
if ($http_host ~* [www|fr|es|uk|de]\.example\.com) {
       rewrite ^/robots.txt$ /robots_index_all.txt break;
    }
    rewrite ^/robots.txt$ /robots_dont_index_anything.txt break;
}
```

So, the behavior i wanted is to serve the robots_index_all.txt file when a bot requests /robots.txt under subdomains www,fr,es,uk and de

Then if the /robots.txt request is made in Any other subdomain i would like to serve the /robots_dont_index_anything.txt

I've been trying this rewrite but it doesn't works consistently, i mean for some of the subdomains work, for some others no, and theres not much other config besides this in the server

Is there anything i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate giving "you are holding it wrong" type of answers but here you go ... First, [don't use "if"](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) unless you are really really have to. Second, don't use variables, they are evel too :)

anyway, what works for me in such cases, when I have a catch-all virtual host is a catch all rewrite, similar to this:

`rewrite ^/robots.txt$ /robots/$http_host.txt last;`

or even try something more adventurous:

```
location = /robots.txt {
      try_files /robots/$http_host.txt /robots/robots.txt;
}
```

so you actually will manage the files per subdomain.

And as OP says he has 900+ domains that are actually servers, what I'd do is to setup a 901'st domain just to respond the robots and place both robots files there. Then just proxy the requests from the original "domain":

```
location = /robots.txt {
      proxy_pass http://my-robots-server-ip/robots/$http_host.txt
}
```

and the proxy should have something like this (well, with limitations):

```
location /robots/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.txt {
      try_files /robots/$1.txt /robots/$1.$2.txt /robots/$1.$2.$3.txt /robots/default.txt;
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we do actually have 900+ subdomains and doing in that way would be unmanageable, Also i have a catch all but not all domains are in there so the way i'm doing is having an include common.cfg in all server blocks, thats the reason i wanted a single rule checking subdomains, IF may be evil, but you're saying isn't usable?

Comment: @jmserra well, there has to be a pattern anyway, you don't intend to manage it in 900+ rewrites, right? give me a pattern I regexp a solution :)

Comment: @jmserra , sorry, misse dyour edit. I've seen more than once if doing strange things. Maybe it is fixed now, can't say, I try not to use it at all.

Comment: @jmserra Ohhhh I see now what you mean, creating 900+ directories and files? these 900+ are different `server` config?

Comment: Well i have about 10 server blocks, for 9 of them i want to use the dont_index_anything... but the other server block is the 'catchall' which may hold about 900 subdomains, and for that i just want to load the index_all.txt for a few subdomains (about 6)  i don't really want to split the server config in another block just for that, as it will make the conf really messy,  thanks

Comment: i see what you mean, but doing your updated answer means i need to have 6 txt files with exactly the same content, no?  as all subdomains that i want to index shares the robots.txt,  ins't there a simpler way of achieving all this?  i mean, it was two lines in apache htaccess :D

Comment: @jmserra eh? `ln -s` why six files? besides, I don't know what your exact pattern is, so the expressions and logic can be improved to better match your situation. Again, you are free to use any other method available, including`if` and `htaccess` :) Just saying.

Comment: alright, the answer wasn't ideal, but i think i maybe just need to get used to nginx, thanks for your help Michael